# Как вывести числа в списке через запятую

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
for i in a:
    if i%2==0:
        print(i, end = ' ')
```

Если добавить , в end то оно будет оставлять в конце лишнюю запятую. Как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 10]
print(*[i for i in a if i % 2 == 0], sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
s = ','.join([str(x) for x in a]) # Из int массива надо сделать массив строк и объединить их с разделителем-запятой
print(s)
```

Comment: `([...])` -> `(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

С такой постановкой вопроса - можно максимально просто:

```
a = [4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 10]
print(str(a)[1:-1])
# 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 10
```